# Loop through the files in each subdirectory and apply a condition

Tags: shell-script, files

I have directory contains many subdirectories and each subdirectory has a couple of files (interested only to files with .ar extension). Now, I need to loop through each subdirectory and check, for example, if the number of the files = 4 then do something to these files, go back to the second subdirectory check the files if = 3 then do another command on them. 
Note that, I have much-complicated conditions I have to apply on the if statement.

something similar to this

```
dir=$1

for sub_dir in $dir; do
    if the number of files in $sub_dir = 4; then
        do something or command line 
    if the number of files in $sub_dir = 3; then
       do another command
    if the number of files in $sub_dir < 3; then
    escape them

    fi
done
```

I need a template for a similar process.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the subdirectories are located directly under the top directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

topdir="$1"

for dir in "$topdir"/*/; do
    set -- "$dir"/*.ar

    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
        # do things when no files were found
        # "$1" will be the pattern "$dir"/*.ar with * unexpanded
    elif [ "$#" -lt 3 ]; then
        # do things when less than 3 files were found
        # the filenames are in "$@"        
    elif [ "$#" -eq 3 ]; then
        # do things when 3 files were found
    elif [ "$#" -eq 4 ]; then
        # do things when 4 files were found
    else
        # do things when more than 4 files were found
    fi
done
```

Or, using `case`:

```
#!/bin/sh

topdir="$1"

for dir in "$topdir"/*/; do
    set -- "$dir"/*.ar

    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
        # no files found
    fi

    case "$#" in
        [12])
            # less than 3 files found
            ;;
        3)
            # 3 files found
            ;;
        4)
            # 4 files found
            ;;
        *)
            # more than 4 files found
    esac
done
```

The branches of the code that needs the filename uses `"$@"` to refer to all filenames in a subdirectory, or `"$1"`, `"$2"` etc. to refer to the individual files.  The filenames will be pathnames including the `$topdir` directory at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
dir=$1

subdirectories = $(find $dir -type d) # find only subdirectories in dir

for subdir in $subdirectories
do
   n_files=$(find $subdir -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l) # find ordinary files in subdir and get it quantity

   if [ $n_files -eq 4 ]
   then
      do_something_4
   fi

   if [ $n_files -eq 3 ]
   then
      do_something_3
   fi

   if [ $n_files -lt 3 ]
   then
      do_something_else
   fi
done
```

Comment: Of cause you can replace series of `if .. then` with `case` operator and put `-name '*.ar'` to `find` filter in `n_files` string.

Comment: I couldn't understand this comment and it seems important because I need to specify only *.ar files to be chosen. would you please re-explain it more clear for me?

Comment: You can change the second find command to include `-name *.ar` so that the name is checked too. I.e., `find $subdir -name *.ar -maxdepth 1 -type f`